# Generic handler for MessageConversionException

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

I want to process the messages from a queue when they have a certain format and can be deserialized to a certain Java class. In order to do that, I created the following method.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "myQueue", containerFactory = "myFactory")
public void receiveMessage(Message message) {
    service.process(message);
}
```

However, when the messages cannot be deserialized to an instance of the Message class, and I get a `org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException`, I want to handle that exception and log the content of the message. What is the standard way to do it? Is there any annotation to define a method for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a custom `ErrorHandler` to the listener container factory - see [Annotation-driven listener endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jms-annotated).

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class AppConfig {

        @Bean
        public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
                DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
                                new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
                factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
                factory.setDestinationResolver(destinationResolver());
                factory.setConcurrency("3-10");
                return factory;
        }
}
```

Add `factory.setErrorHandler(myErrorHandler())`.

Comment: Many thanks @Gary, is there any way to access the message content from the handler?

Comment: I don't believe the conversion exception has a reference to the original message; I think you'd have to wrap the message converter in your own, catch the exception and throw a new exception with the `Message` as a property.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and adding `ErrorHandler` didn't help me. The JMS queue still tried to process failing message indefinitely.

However, instead of unmurshalling "on the fly" the bound @Payload parameter, I unmarshall it manually:

```
@Autowired
private MarshallingMessageConverter xmlMessageConverter;
...

@JmsListener(...)
public void fromQueue(@Payload javax.jms.Message jmsMessage,
                      @Header(value = "UUID", required = false) UUID uuid) {
    try {
        MyCustomeMessage message = (MyCustomeMessage) xmlMessageConverter.fromMessage(jmsMessage);
        // process message ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception in Queue for message uuid [{}]", uuid, e);
    }
}
```

We faced with this situation when I changed the structure of incoming message and old messages couldn't be processed anymore.